# How can I use separate Apim-Subscription-Key for different APIs?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I have 4 backend APIs and all are listed under single APIM instance. Also I have created 4 different subscription-keys (apart from existing "Built-in all-access subscription") from "Subscriptions" option to be used for authorization of APIS. While creating subscription keys, I configured score as "API" and selected separate API from dropdown list. but still my API's do not validate with new subscription keys.

While testing from POSTMAN, any call to any API accepts only old subscription-key (Built-in all-access subscription).

What mistake I am doing here while configuration?

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of "Subscription" tab page ? I test it in my side, but it works fine. I can use the new subscription key to request my APIM api.

Comment: @HuryShen I have attached it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I will continue to test it next weekday.

Comment: I test in my side again, but it works fine even though I set all of the configuration same with yours. Could you please double check if you can use the new subscription key in postman ? If still doesn't work, is there any other configuration which you have done for the subscription key ?

Comment: Hi Hury, Yes I had test with new keys thru postman. But it was not working for new keys, but fine for old key. Not sure why not accepting new keys created specifically for individual Api.

Comment: Could you please check if you have changed the [header name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMMcW.png) of subscription key ?

Comment: Yes,  I have changed it. I have removed ocp prefix. I have now "apim-subscription-key".

Comment: Hi Rahul, I'm sorry that I still can't reproduce your problem. I suggest you to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) a support request on azure portal to ask azure support team help.
And may I know if your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593657/does-apim-forward-same-bearer-token-to-backend-api-oauth-2-0-and-azure-aad) was solved ? If it was solved, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks.

Comment: sure I will do that. Thanks @HuryShen

Comment: Do your apim endpoint have Products? Are the apis you want to access in that product?